# Eclipselink: Custom StructConverter for Spatial never called

Tags: java, oracle, jpa, eclipselink, spatial

I've ran into a problem concerning complex objects and Eclipselink which I can't seem to solve. I need to write / read spatial data as `SDO_GEOMETRY` to my Oracle database.

I used to use `oracle.spatial.geometry.JGeometry`, but for querying reasons I need to switch to `org.geolatte.geom.Geometry` (which is the spatial type used by QueryDSL). So I wrote a custom implementation of `org.eclipse.persistence.platform.database.converters.StructConverter` to handle the conversion from `org.geolatte.geom.Geometry` to `SDO_GEOMETRY` / `Struct`.

I used `org.eclipse.persistence.platform.database.oracle.converters.JGeometryConverter` as a template.

```
import com.mysema.query.sql.spatial.JGeometryConverter;
import java.lang.invoke.MethodHandle;
import java.lang.invoke.MethodHandles;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Struct;
import oracle.spatial.geometry.JGeometry;
import org.eclipse.persistence.platform.database.converters.StructConverter;
import org.geolatte.geom.Geometry;

public class GeometryConverter implements StructConverter {
    private static final String JGEOMETRY_DB_TYPE = "MDSYS.SDO_GEOMETRY";
    private Class JGEOMETRY_CLASS;
    private MethodHandle loadJSMethod;
    private MethodHandle storeJSMethod;

    public GeometryConverter() {
        try {
            JGEOMETRY_CLASS = Class.forName("oracle.spatial.geometry.JGeometry");
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }

        MethodHandles.Lookup lookup = MethodHandles.lookup();
        try {
            loadJSMethod = lookup.unreflect(JGEOMETRY_CLASS.getMethod("loadJS", new Class[] {
                Struct.class
            }));
            storeJSMethod = lookup.unreflect(JGEOMETRY_CLASS.getMethod("storeJS", new Class[] {
                JGEOMETRY_CLASS,
                Connection.class
            }));
        } catch (IllegalAccessException | NoSuchMethodException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public String getStructName() {
        return JGEOMETRY_DB_TYPE;
    }

    @Override
    public Class getJavaType() {
        return Geometry.class;
    }

    @Override
    public Object convertToObject(Struct struct) throws SQLException {
        System.out.println("-------------------- CALLED convertToObject");
        if (struct == null) {
            return null;
        }
        try {
            return JGeometryConverter.convert((JGeometry)loadJSMethod.invokeWithArguments(new Object[] {
                struct
            }));

        } catch (Throwable throwable) {
            throw new SQLException(throwable);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public Struct convertToStruct(Object geometry, Connection connection) throws SQLException {
        System.out.println("-------------------- CALLED convertToStruct");
        if (geometry == null) {
            return null;
        }
        try {
            return (Struct) storeJSMethod.invokeWithArguments(new Object[] {
                JGeometryConverter.convert((Geometry)geometry), connection
            });
        } catch (Throwable throwable) {
            throw new SQLException(throwable);
        }
    }
}
```

My entity class is annotated the following way:

```
//Real package replaced by 'myPkg' for privacy reasons
@StructConverter(name = "Geometry", converter = "myPkg.GeometryConverter")
@Table(name = "ENTRY", catalog = "")
public class Entry implements Serializable {
    ...

    @Column(name = "LOCATION")
    @Convert("Geometry")
    private Geometry location;
    ...
}
```

But for some odd reason the method `convertToStruct` of my converter is not called when calling `entityManager.persist(myEntryObject)`.
Instead I get the following exception:

```
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Invalid column type
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.setObjectCritical(OraclePreparedStatement.java:8488)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.setObjectInternal(OraclePreparedStatement.java:7995)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.setObjectInternal(OraclePreparedStatement.java:8735)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.setObject(OraclePreparedStatement.java:8714)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatementWrapper.setObject(OraclePreparedStatementWrapper.java:219)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.databaseaccess.DatabasePlatform.setParameterValueInDatabaseCall(DatabasePlatform.java:2506)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.platform.database.oracle.Oracle9Platform.setParameterValueInDatabaseCall(Oracle9Platform.java:525)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.databaseaccess.BindCallCustomParameter.set(BindCallCustomParameter.java:69)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.databaseaccess.DatabasePlatform.setParameterValueInDatabaseCall(DatabasePlatform.java:2500)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.platform.database.oracle.Oracle9Platform.setParameterValueInDatabaseCall(Oracle9Platform.java:525)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.databaseaccess.DatabaseCall.prepareStatement(DatabaseCall.java:797)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.databaseaccess.DatabaseAccessor.basicExecuteCall(DatabaseAccessor.java:621)
    ... 101 more
```

What is so odd about this is that when retrieving `Entry` objects via the `EntityManager` `convertToObject` is indeed called and it works perfectly. But every time I try to insert / update an `Entry` it doesn't work.

Is there any additional configuration I have to do to make EclipseLink recognize my converter? What else could be the cause of this problem?

I hope someone can help me. Thank you in advance.

**EDIT**

My persistence unit looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="1.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence persistence_1_0.xsd">
  <persistence-unit name="jtaUnit" transaction-type="JTA">
    <provider>org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider</provider>
    <jta-data-source>java:app/aphrodite4</jta-data-source>
    <exclude-unlisted-classes>false</exclude-unlisted-classes>
    <properties>
        <property name="toplink.target-database" value ="oracle.toplink.essentials.extension.spatial.Oracle10SpatialPlatform"/>
        <property name="eclipselink.cache.shared.default" value="false"/>
        <property name="javax.persistence.validation.group.pre-persist" value="javax.validation.groups.Default"/>
        <property name="javax.persistence.validation.group.pre-update" value="javax.validation.groups.Default,myPkg.ConstraintGroups.Update"/>
    </properties>
  </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

I am loading it the following way:

```
@PersistenceContext(unitName = "jtaUnit")
protected EntityManager em;
```

Comment: Based on the code in the stack trace, I'd guess that the Geometry instance in your object is loaded with a different class loader then the one used to load the persistence unit and GeometryConverter classes. The DatabasePlatform.setParameterValueInDatabaseCall tries looking up the converter using the parameter's class.  Assuming the converter was properly loaded, it would be in that list and the look up would only fail if the Class instances for the Geometry were considered different. You will have to look at how you are loading the persistence context and the class instance.

Comment: Thank's for your input, @Chris. I have edited my post to include information about my persistence unit. I am definitely using `em` for persisting my `Geometry` object. The only cause of the problem I can think of is that my converter is not added to the database platform (Shouldn't `@StructConverter` do it automatically?). However, wouldn't that mean that retrieving an object would also fail? (Which it doesn't as mentioned above)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After not finding a solution to the problem mentioned above I was able to work out a workaround.

I wrote the following Database Function:

```
create or replace FUNCTION WITHIN_DISTANCE(g sdo_geometry, lon number, lat number, distLimit number)
RETURN VARCHAR2 AS 

dist NUMBER;
result VARCHAR2(5);
tmpGeo SDO_GEOMETRY;

BEGIN
  tmpGeo := SDO_GEOMETRY(2001, 8307, SDO_POINT_TYPE(lon, lat, NULL), NULL, NULL);
  SELECT SDO_GEOM.SDO_DISTANCE(g, tmpGeo, 0.005) INTO dist FROM dual;

  IF dist <= distLimit THEN
    result := 'TRUE';
  ELSE
    result := 'FALSE';
  END IF;

  RETURN result;

END WITHIN_DISTANCE;
```

To use this function in a QueryDsl query I use the following code:

```
Predicate pred = Expressions.stringTemplate("function('WITHIN_DISTANCE', {0}, {1}, {2}, {3})" , 
                        QEntry.entry.location,
                        loc.getLon(),
                        loc.getLat(),
                        crit.getRadius()).eq("TRUE");
```